# Using an existing Snowflake tables file format for pandas read_csv

Tags: pandas

I have the following file format in Snowflake for a table X. This loaded the s3 files correctly into snowflake however I need to do some transformations (using pandas) *before* it reaches snowflake.

```
CREATE FILE FORMAT IF NOT EXISTS a.x
field_delimiter = ' '
EMPTY_FIELD_AS_NULL = True
skip_header = 1
escape = NONE
FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"'
NULL_IF=('NULL','',' ','NULL','NULL','//N', '\\N') 
RECORD_DELIMITER = '\n';
```

This is what I've tried: `engine='python'` and `quoting = csv.QUOTE_ALL` and `skiprows = 1` (because the headers are not in double quotes, see below for image of file):

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_name, sep=' ', lineterminator='\n')
```

but this is the error I keep seeing:

> ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 6 fields in line
> 221, saw 7

This is a sample of what the file looks like, it contains headers:

```
publisher_domain_id page_url    normalized_page_url impression_id   ts  user_custom user_ip_country user_ip_region  user_timezone   browser_family  browser_version device_type device_family   os_family   os_version  affiliatable_links_count    skimwords_count page_referrer   datehour
"1643288"   "htt21" "vioscope-gemini-o1"    "6954BBC"   "2022-01-08 08:31:50"       "za"        "-120"  "Opera Mini"    "4.4.33961" "mobile"    "Generic Feature Phone" "Other"     "0" "0" "http://wwera-mini&ei=JEvZY75WQCg&start=50&sa=N"    "2022-01-08 08:00:00"
"1643288"   "https://www.a-wort"    "vd/how-ryan-duof-at"   "061E9974B233"  "2022-01-08 19:01:41"       "pk"        "-300"  "UC Browser"    "13.4.0"    "mobile"    "Infinix X6511B"    "Android"       "3" "0" "https://www.google.com.pk/"    "2022-01-08 19:00:00"
"1643284"   "https://wws-le-bi=IwARLj-_obRhpwdE1A"  "vd-le-se-fn-pase-ri"   "170331464" "2022-01-08 12:49:40"       "gp"        "240"   "Opera Mobile"  "66.2.3445" "mobile"    "Generic Smartphone"    "Android"       "2" "0" "https://m.facebook.com/"   "2022-01-08 12:00:00"
"1647635"   "https://wwdzb/affl-senmare"    "vntaretal-mia-mre" "4EC93F7E3C93E4"    "2022-01-08 22:24:03"       "ru"        "-180"  "YandexMobileBot"   "3.0"   "mobile"    "Spider"    "iOS"   "8.1"   "0" "0"     "2022-01-08 22:00:00"
"1643288"   "htpodcaster-ovid"  "viaster-g-kfrom-id"    "6B4A8946D6"    "2022-01-08 05:31:35"       "jp"        "-540"  "Firefox Mobile"    "95.0"  "mobile"    "Generic Smartphone"    "Android"       "0" "0"     "2022-01-08 05:00:00"
```

Comment: could you try data = pd.read_csv('file1.csv', on_bad_lines='skip'). Could you also paste couple of records ,  can check what is causing issue.

Comment: @Anand just pasted an example row into the question, it contains the headers and the next row

Answer (score 1):

This worked and I didn't have to skip any lines! I was trying to match sep=' ' as I have in Snowflake, but this worked instead, I'm still not sure why:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_name, sep='\t',skiprows=1, header=None)
```